# Visual Studio 2013 не запускает программу из за ucrtbased.dll

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

я распаковал openCV прописал переменную и path 
сделал настройки в проекте, ничего красным не светится - при компиляции ошибка

ucrtbased.dll  не найден, переустановите программу 
vs2013, win 8.1

и еще куча в консоли.
что я делаю не так?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>



using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


    Mat image;
    image = imread("icecream.jpg", 1);   // Read the file

    if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image);                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\VS2013\11\ConsolCV\x64\Debug\ConsolCV.exe'. Symbols loaded.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv330\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world330d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\concrt140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- 'ConsolCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
- The program '[4896] ConsolCV.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.

Comment: ucrtbased.dll имеется в системе? А релизная сборка работает?

Comment: всмысле, релизная?

Comment: В прямом. Студия умеет собирать дебажную и релизную сборку. У вас, вероятно, дебажная не работает. Как с релизной дела обстоят?

Comment: эта же ошибка,,,

Comment: ucrtbased.dll в системе имеется?

Comment: поиск не нашел ,

Comment: Ответ есть тут [EN SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41970093/6125029)

Answer (score 3):

`ucrtbased.dll` — это библиотека, относящаяся к компоненту Windows 10 под названием *Universal CRT*.

Его отсутствие означает две вещи:

1. Ваша ОС — Windows 8.1 или ниже.
2. При установке студии вы забыли отметить компоненты *Windows Universal C Runtime* и *Windows 10 SDK*, либо по незнанию сняли с них отметку:

   [image: Экранный снимок установщика Microsoft Visual Studio]

Важно: для корректной установки Universal C Runtime [необходимо наличие](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ccde5592-c73e-4232-add0-918a1c04a5a0/visual-studio-2017-universal-c-runtime-crt-for-windows-7?forum=visualstudiogeneral#3669c2f4-83e8-4ce0-bf08-b548b1201f4a) обновления [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) «Обновление для универсальной среды выполнения C в Windows».

Однако дальнейшее распространение вашего приложения также потребует и установки у его пользователей данной среды исполнения, а также указанного обновления и всех его зависимостей. Так что альтернативный вариант — откатиться на более ранние версии Visual Studio, не завязанные на Windows 10, либо использовать какой-нибудь альтернативный компилятор (например, MinGW-x64) вместо встроенного `cl`.

***P. S:*** как сказано в [одном из ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44334289/2553424) на En.SO, экспресс-версия студии может не содержать в себе указанных компонентов. Тогда потребуется установить отдельно идущий [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).